# Today Extension's Content is not displayed except a title on real iPhone machine

Tags: iphone, widget, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

I'm developing an app with Today Extension.
My app's name is on Today, but contents are not displayed below that.
This phenomenon happens only I run from Application's scheme on real iPhone machine.
Everything goes fine if I run from today extenion's scheme.
Or, if I run on iPhone simulator, scheme is not the problem.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: The problem has been fixed!

Comment: This problem was happened because the pixel size of graphic file was too big.  Memory Today can handle is so small that too-big-resource-file can be stopped by the iOS.

Comment: The solution is to use graphics that have less pixels.  Be aware that the problem is not the file size but the pixel size.

Comment: See articles below that I wrote ;)   (Japanese)
http://dev.classmethod.jp/etc/today-extension-today-extension-memory-allocation/

http://dev.classmethod.jp/etc/today-extension-today-extension-memory-allocation2/